# Smooth edges option not working on Windows Server 2008 Standard SP2 while in remote session

Tags: fonts, windows-server-2008, appearance, font-smoothing

Text displayed on the sceen is very hard to read because of the hard edges, but looking under **Appearance Settings -> Effects** the option to `Use the following method to smooth edges of screen fonts` is disabled (grayed).

I adjusted the connection speed manually (remote session) and checked visual effects, and now I am able to activate ClearType. But the edges are still sharp.

How can I otherwise smooth edges of screen fonts?

Comment: I don't have a Windows Server instance running but a windows search for "ClearType" might yield some results - though I'm pretty sure it is activated by default

Comment: @benjaminS it's not activated, the checkbox for smooth edges where "ClearType" is an option is unchecked and disabled (grayed)

Comment: Another guess - are you using a remote desktop session to access your server? If I remember correctly you can adjust the visual effects when starting a rdp session in the performance tab. I think you have to setup your connection speed manually to adjust the settings then

Comment: @benjaminS - you are correct, it is a remote desktop session. I adjusted the connection speed manually and checked visual effects, and now I am able to activate ClearType. But the edges are still sharp?

Comment: Can you try changing the color-settings in the RDP options to 24 bit? [The screenshot](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/291591) shows the differences - the upper one is 32 bit and the one at the bottom is 24 bit

Comment: @benjaminS - After changing the color-setting in RDP option to 24 bit without result and changing it back to 32 bit, the smooth edges effect works... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the options for "ClearType" and the method to smooth the edges of screen fonts is disabled, then you are probably using a Remotedesktop-connection to manage your server. If so, check the **Experience** tab when connecting to your server.

[image: ExperienceTab from the Remote-Desktop-dialogue]

Choose the connection speed manually and allow the visual effects. Also check the color-settings under the **Display** tab and change it to 24-bit.
If it still doesn't work then changing the color-option to 32 again seems to do the trick.